# Channel Search in Youtube Data API within a particular category

Tags: youtube-api

I want to get all the channels within one particular category say "X".How can i achieve this using youtube data API?
Getting all the channels is easy and we can get these on the basis of searched keyword.

Answer (score 1):

With the Youtube API v3 the channels can be filtered by the Freebase topic ID, besides keyword

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list